# Change subcaption label format

Tags: memoir, subfloats, subcaption, cleveref

I need to have subcaption labels (and references) be of the format

> Fig. 1a

Instead of the default "(a)", and be able to reference them with `\cref`

Unfortunately, I can't seem to get any subcaption related commands change the format of the subcaption "label" (is that the correct name for this?)

This is as close as I can get (while still having `\cref` work for normal, non-subfigure figures).

As you can see, I'm using `memoir`. The problem with the below code is that the references using `\cref` start with the figure counter (the first "1" below), and I can't seem to get rid of it. I understand this is the wrong way to handle it (I change the counter to include a name/label instead of changing the caption format). Any proper solution is very welcome, failing that, a hack to fix my hack is welcome as well!

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\newsubfloat{figure}

\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{Fig. \arabic{figure}\alph{subfigure}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}

\crefformat{subfigure}{#2{}#1{}#3{}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\subbottom[first subfigure \label{fig:first}]{\fbox{Numero uno}}
\subbottom[second subfigure \label{fig:second}]{\fbox{Numero dos}}
\end{figure}
\cref{fig:first}

\cref{fig:second}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT** it seems also that if I don't use `\caption` the figure number isn't incremented and a following normal figure will use the same figure number. Is there an automated way to change this behaviour? Currently, I'm adding a `\addtocounter{figure}{1}` in each subfig only figure, which has the desired effect.

Comment: Isn't it simpler for you to use use say the subfig package instead?

Comment: @daleif I thought that package was deprecated. I also didn't find any way to do what I wanted there...

Comment: Where did you see that information? As far as I now it us the `subfigure` package that is no longer maintained.

Comment: @daleif my mistake. Still couldn't get as close as I am above with that package.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite an unusual request/demand. Here is one solution, but it probably will make a mess at normal use of figure referencing:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}

\newsubfloat{figure}
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{Fig.~\arabic{figure}\alph{subfigure}}

\crefformat{subfigure}{#2#1#3}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]\centering
     \renewcommand{\thefigure}{} 
\subbottom[first subfigure  \label{fig:1}]{\fbox{figure numero uno}}
    \hfil
\subbottom[second subfigure \label{fig:2}]{\fbox{figure numero dos}}
    \stepcounter{figure}
\end{figure}
    some text
\begin{figure}[h]\centering
     \renewcommand{\thefigure}{} 
\subbottom[first subfigure  \label{fig:3}]{\fbox{figure numero uno}}
    \hfil
\subbottom[second subfigure \label{fig:4}]{\fbox{figure numero dos}}
   \stepcounter{figure}
\end{figure}
some text
\begin{figure}[h]\centering
\fbox{some "normal" figure}
    \caption{normal figure}
    \label{fig:5}
\end{figure}

\cref{fig:1} and \cref{fig:4} and also \cref{fig:5}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
Desired look-out is achieved by use `\renewcommand{\thefigure}{}` in each float with subfigures and  `\stepcounter{figure}` before end of `figure` float. Now I hope is fulfilled your requests.

Comment: There are also normal figures, so I can't mess up their label formatting. I understand the unusuality of the request, and believe me I don't agree with the result, but I was given a task to make a 1:1 copy of a badly formatted Word document. So I want to see how close I can get it!

Comment: Well, this can be partially fulfilled by moving `\renewcommand{\thefigure}{}` inside float, see edit of my answer.