# Rotated page starts at the edge of the paper

Tags: vertical-alignment, subcaption, rotating

I'm rotating a page because of a wide figure, but it then begins just at the edge of the page, with no margins. I'm puzzled as I expected the rotated page to inherit the margins of the document it is inserted in. Further, I'd like it to be centered in the page.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaysfigure}
  \subcaptionbox{Returns $\alpha = 1$}{\includegraphics[width=.33\linewidth]{Rendimientos1}}%
  \subcaptionbox{Returns $\alpha = \frac{1}{2}$}{\includegraphics[width=.33\linewidth]{Rendimientos1-2}}%
  \subcaptionbox{Returns $\alpha = 2$}{\includegraphics[width=.33\linewidth]{Rendimientos2}}%
  \caption{Returns}
\end{sidewaysfigure}


\end{document}
```

Also, my subfigures are too close together. I've tried changing the width of the `\subcaptionbox` as

```
  \subcaptionbox{Returns $\alpha = 1$}[.3\linewidth]{\includegraphics[width=.33\linewidth]{Rendimientos1}}%
```

but this seems to affect the size of the figure, rather than that of the box.

Finally, I get subfigures labelled (A), (B), ... and I'd rather have (a), (b). I'm guessing this has to do with the default option `labelformat=parens`, but I'm unsure how to modify it. I've tried

```
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\alph{subfigure}}
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

**Edit:**
I've managed to get more space between the figures and include a margin. In the process, I've rewritten my code to something easier (for me) to understand. However, the solution is quite *ad hoc* and doesn't seem too elegant. In addition, the output still uses uppercase letters to identify the subfigures.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}


\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaysfigure}
    \vspace{13cm}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.33\linewidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{Rendimientos12}%
         \caption{$\alpha=\frac{1}{2}$}
    \end{subfigure}% 
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.33\linewidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{Rendimientos1}%
         \caption{$\alpha=1$}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.33\linewidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{Rendimientos2}%
         \caption{$\alpha=2$}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{General caption}
 \end{sidewaysfigure}

 \end{document}
```

My questions:

1. Is there a more elegant alternative to the use of `\vspace`?
2. How do I change the format of the subcaption to lowercase? I've tried alternatives proposed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321707/subcaption-subtable-change-the-format-of-reference) or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278047/change-subcaption-label-format) to no avail. I'm guessing it may have to do with the document class.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: @Davislor, thanks. I'm looking forward to learning a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For point 1, see here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/239570/101651.

For point 2, you guessed right, the `amsbook` class forces the caption labels to be in small caps.

With

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@captionheadfont}{\scshape}{}{}{}
\makeatother
```

you can avoid it. Then with

```
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{labelfont=sc}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelfont=normal}
```

you can set all caption labels as small caps but subfigure labels as normal font.

I think these corrections don't affect other settings of the documentclass, but pay attention.

```
% see here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/239570/101651
\RequirePackage{rotating}
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@captionheadfont}{\scshape}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{labelfont=sc}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelfont=normal}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaysfigure}\centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.33\linewidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{example-image-a}%
         \caption{$\alpha=\frac{1}{2}$}
    \end{subfigure}% 
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.33\linewidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{example-image-b}%
         \caption{$\alpha=1$}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.33\linewidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{example-image-c}%
         \caption{$\alpha=2$}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{General caption}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
\end{document}
```

[image]